# Finding a change of Basis Matrix Of Polynomial Degree Less than 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I am doing some practice questions and I'm not too sure where to start on this one:

1. Consider the bases $B = \{p_1,p_2\}$ and $B' = \{q_1,q_2\}$ of P$_1$, the polynomials of degree $\le$ 1, where $p_1 = 2$; $p_2 = x - 1$;  $q_1 = x + 3$; $q_2 = x + 1.$
   (a) Find the transition matrix from B' to B.
   (b) Find the transition matrix from B to B'.
   (c) Let $p = 2x - 1$. Compute $[p]_B$, the coordinates of $p$ with respect to $B$, and then use (b) to find $[p]_{B'}$, the coordinates of $p$ with respect to $B'$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The transition matrix from basis $B_1$ to basis $B_2$ is found by just writing the vectors in $B_1$ in the coordinates of $B_2$. In you case, you need to find
$\begin{bmatrix} p_1 \end{bmatrix}_{B'}, \begin{bmatrix} p_2 \end{bmatrix}_{B'}, \begin{bmatrix} q_1 \end{bmatrix}_{B}, \begin{bmatrix} q_2 \end{bmatrix}_{B}$. These vectors are
\begin{align}
p_1 &= 1 (x + 3) - 1 (x + 1), \quad \text{which implies} \\
\begin{bmatrix} p_1 \end{bmatrix}_{B'} &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}, \\
p_2 &= -1 (x + 3) + 2(x + 1), \quad \text{which implies} \\
\begin{bmatrix} p_2 \end{bmatrix}_{B'}  &= \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\2 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Hence, the transition matrix from $B$ to $B'$ is just 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} p_1 \end{bmatrix}_{B'} & \begin{bmatrix} p_1 \end{bmatrix}_{B'}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Can you follow these steps to find the transition matrix from $B'$ to $B$? The actual computation boils down to finding the coefficients (coordinates). How did I do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm for finding the transition matrix and it is as following:

- Augment the matrix representing the basis for the coordinate system you want to convert to, with the matrix representing the basis for the coordinate system you want to convert from; so in this case
  $$ \left[
      \begin{array}{c|c}
        B&B'\\
      \end{array}
  \right] $$
- RREF the augmented matrix and what's on the left side of the column should be $I_n$ and on the right side it should be $T_{B'}^B$

  1. $$ \left[
         \begin{array}{cc|cc}
            2&-1&3&1\\
            0&1&1&1
         \end{array}
     \right] $$
  2. $$ \left[
         \begin{array}{cc|cc}
            1&0&2&1\\
            0&1&1&1
         \end{array}
     \right] $$
  3. $T_{B'}^B$ = $$ \begin{bmatrix} 2&1\\ 1&1\\ \end{bmatrix} $$